# With Java regex find functions with any number of nesting

Tags: java, regex

Hello fellow programmers

i have a small problem and can't seem to find the right answere.

So my idea is i get a String with a predefined function from me.
It will look something like this:

```java
 String expression = "map(%set@IDENTIFIER%, get(%key@Longitude:Number%), get(%key@Latitude:Number%), map(%set@IDENTIFIER%, get(%key@Longitude:Number%), get(%key@Latitude:Number%)))";
```

It can be much more complicated or even simpler when i only use get for example.

What i want to do is to split every function in to its parameter this can also be functions or a normal String or Number.

What i thought is i can use regex to do this but i can't seem to find the right thing.

My regex so far:

```java
String regex = "((?<method>map|get)\\((?<parameter>\\%(?<dynamic>set\\@[a-zA-Z_]+|\\$[0-9]+|key\\@[a-zA-Z_]+|set\\@[a-zA-Z_]+)(?<type>:[a-zA-Z]+)*\\%,*)+\\))";
```

What i do is

```java
Pattern pa = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = pa.matcher(expression);
while (m.find()) {
   System.out.println("Method " + m.group("method"));
   System.out.println("Parameter " + m.group("parameter"));
   System.out.println("Type" + m.group("type"));
}
```

My Output is than this: 
Method get 
Parameter %key@Longitude:Number% 
Type:Number 
Method get 
Parameter %key@Latitude:Number% 
Type:Number 
Method get 
Parameter %key@Longitude:Number% 
Type:Number 
Method get 
Parameter %key@Latitude:Number% 
Type:Number

But what i miss is the function map with all its parameter.

Hope it is kind of understandable what i mean.

Comment: You miss it because all the methods are nested inside the `map`s. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/nG8hX0/1). Java regex does not support recursion.

Comment: Probably regex is not your solution here.

Comment: This sounds more like a job for a recursive descent parser. Check out ANTLR for example if you do not want to write it yourself.

Comment: @Sorcen that looks interesting thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this ANTRL syntax.

```
grammar Method;

method      : ('map' | 'get') '(' element (',' element )* ')';
element     : method | parameter;
parameter   : '%' dynamic type* '%';
dynamic     : 'set' '@' ID | 'key' '@' ID | '$' NUMBER;
type        : ':' ID;

ID          : [a-zA-Z]+;
NUMBER      : [0-9]+;
Skip        : [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip;
```

Result is

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

Java regular expressions do not support recursion, which is required for arbitrary nested parenthesis matching in a regex. Even if it did, the best solution would be to actually parse the expression.

If you don't want to use a proper parser, then you should tokenize it. Split it into a stream of function starts, parameters, and function ends, and then add logic to process that stream.